# How to remove word from line if word macth with other cell value : excel

Tags: excel

I have excel sheet with data demo data given bellow .

```
 A        B                                C
Abc      In this line Abc               In this line 
Dog      Remove Dog from this line      Remove from this line
Cat      Cat Remove from here           Remove from here
```

I have words in column "A" and lines in column "B". I want to  remove word from column "B" that listed in column "A" and want result in Column "C" as above ex show. is their any formula that can do this. I search but cant find suitable formula or answer. im new so not know which way is best to do this. hope got some help from here.

Comment: Like the [SUBSTITUTE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/substitute-function-6434944e-a904-4336-a9b0-1e58df3bc332)?

Comment: @DirkReichel thanks for reply  something like this =SUBSTITUTE(A2, "Sales", "Cost")
 

Substitutes Cost for Sales (Cost Data)
 

Cost Data   but not this one as my values change in every row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use SUBSTITUE(text, old_text, new_text) and TRIM to get rid of extra spaces.

Ex.

```
   A        B                                C
1 Abc      In this line Abc               =TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(B1,A1,""))
2 Dog      Remove Dog from this line      =TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(B2,A2,""))
3 Cat      Cat Remove from here           =TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(B3,A3,""))
```

Answer (score 1):

simple version:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(B1, A1, "")
```

to remove only whole words (thanks Dirk for the comment):

```
=TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(" "&B1&" "," "&A1&" "," "))
```

Comment: `=TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(" "&B1&" "," "&A1&" "," "))` would never cut longer words... (still: stuff like dots, commas or brackets are problematic)

Comment: thanks for help me, every row has different value, so i want to that formula match column "B" value with column "A" and if any text from column "B" exit in column "A" that word remove from line . like my above ex:  column a contain dog word and column b also contain dog word in line "Remove Dog from this line " and in c formula remove word dog from line. hope you understand

Comment: @deccc ehm, you just copy & paste the formula to other rows and Excel will change relative references to the current row